# Learn IP address of sender of a self-destructing email

Tags: email, forensics, anonymity

How can I know the IP address of the sender who sent me a self-destructing email? If not the IP address... what all information can be extracted?

Comment: What do you mean by a "self destruct email"? Emails can't destroy themselves, since they're stored on your computer. The only thing one could do is sending an email that only consists of a link. But even then it's usually trivial to store the content of the link target.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for correcting me. Can i get any information from that link? So that i can trace out the one who sent that email?

Comment: Your question is so low on details, that it's hard to say anything useful about it.

Comment: What all details needed to help me out? Let me know... Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Since there is no such thing as a “self-destruct email”, you'll need to explain what you mean by this phrase. What distinguishes this email from other emails?

Comment: Self-destructing emails delete the original message once the recipient has read it. The only way around for someone to copy, a self-destructing email would be taking screenshot. Some of the services will make it difficult to make a readable screen grab. When coming to other services providers like google(gmail),Microsoft(hotmail) every email will be in our inbox or else in spam.

Comment: @Gilles Let me introduce you to - google.com its a beautiful website, very neat and clean. Type in self destructing email services and woah! so many services available :)

Comment: @KarmicDice Since there is no such thing as a “self-destruct email” (although there are people prepared to sell you one), what do *you* mean by “self-destruct email”? What makes you think you've received one? P.S. posting the full text (including headers — especially the headers) of what you have would probably make this question answerable.

Comment: Steps to do: Have a self-destruct email, email self destruct mail to urself, chk ur test mail, mail gets deleted.. then, change ur opinion.

Comment: @`Gilles Of course it exists. Write "Please delete after reading" into the mail. Then it self destructs for well behaved receivers. @KarmicDice it's impossible to delete an email you send to somebody, unless you're prepared to hack his computer. You can only send an email containing a link, where the website at the end of the link disables itself. But screenshotting or saving such a website is still trivial. So Gilles is right that there is no such thing as a self destruct email. [Excluding a corporate context, where admins have control over email clients]

Comment: I got that email from "SD Message" After 60seconds the message was deleted. As the provider policy also states that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes i received the link. With in some time the link got disabled itself... I want to know is there anyway to find the one who sent me mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email itself didn't get deleted, since that's impossible. The email just consists of a link to a website, which won't work after the timeout.

This website uses a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">` tag to refresh after 60 seconds. But within those 60 seconds you can easily view the source code, and save it. One example I saved looks like this: http://nopaste.info/aa9ca35dde_nl.html

For this specific sender(sdmessage.com), it even displays the sender's IP address. Just save it. If you forgot to save it, you're out of luck.

Comment: No. The link was disabled in 60seconds.

Comment: @VenInd You're right. Disabling javascript is not enough, you need to disable redirects as well. Forgot to mention that, since I already had them disabled before.

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely you will find out. You need to get the logs of the server it was stored on:

- Ask the service provider nicely
- Threaten the service provider
- subpoena the service provider
- steal the logs from the service provider